# Reassign a global variable

Tags: typescript

The piece of code is supposed to stub built-in globals (for testing or debugging purposes):

```
function foo() {
    Date = bar();
}
```

`Date` global already declared in TypeScript library definitions, and rhis will cause an error:

> Cannot assign to 'Date' because it is a constant or a read-only property.

I'm trying to avoid referring it as `this['Date']` because it's incompatible with strict mode and `window['Date']` or `global['Date']` because the code is cross-platform, and the only reliable way to get a global is `eval` (I'm trying to avoid it, too).

What are the options here? Is the extraction of `foo` function from .ts to untyped .js file the only option?

Comment: I suggest: `(window || global)['Date']`. Yes it is inelegant…

Comment: @Paleo I'm avoiding it not because it's not elegant but because it is unreliable and backfired on me before. Depending on the precedence in which variables are matched, it will fail If browser environment has `window.global` (to shim some Node things or whatever) or Node has `global.window` to stub DOM.

Comment: Then just set both `window['Date']` and `global['date']` if exists and are objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date` is a `const` global variable according to [the TypeScript standard library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.8.2/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L819).  If you want to be able to assign or reassign it with approval from TypeScript (meaning that the compiler recognizes the assignment as valid), you'd need to supplant the standard library with your own edited local version.  But I gather you don't want to do that, since presumably you still want nobody else to freely reassign `Date` or the like.

If you are actually considering moving your function to unchecked JavaScript (assuming you're not using the `--checkJs` [compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) which would probably just bring the problem back), a less drastic measure is to suppress the error for that one line using the [`@ts-ignore`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments) directive comment:

```
function foo() {
    //@ts-ignore: Cannot reassign to const Date    
    Date = bar();
}
```

Note that this does not make the compiler recognize the reassignment as valid; it merely prevents any error on the next line from being reported.  So, for example, if you misspell `bar()` as `barr()` there will still be no error reported.  If the suppressed error would have caused problems in other parts of your code, those problems will still exist.  This is not a concern with reassigning a `const` variable, since the compiler still maintains the variable's type and `const`ness after such an error.  But do observe that as a tool, the `@ts-ignore` directive is both blunt and dangerous, and should only be used with care.  Or, as the linked handbook documentation says,

> we recommend you use th[ese] comments *very sparingly*.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Wanted to be sure I didn't miss something with lib definitions. Totally forgot about @ts-ignore, and yes, it seems like it is the best way to handle this. Thanks!